# Pointwise convergence and Dirichlet's theorem on Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

> Let $f\left(x\right)=x\cos \left(α x\right)$ at $\left[-π,π\right]$ for $λ \in \mathbb{R}$.  Let $S$ be $f\left(x\right)$'s corresponding Fourier Series.
>   Prove or disprove: **1)** if $λ \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $S$ Pointwise-converges to $f\left(x\right)$.
>   **2)** If $λ = m + \dfrac{1}{2}$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $S$ Pointwise-converges to $f\left(x\right)$.

**Thoughts -**
Since $f\left(x\right)$ is continuous (multiplication of continuous functions)  in $\left[-π,π\right]$ we could use Dirichlet's theorem and just say that $S$ should converge to $f\left(x\right)$, it just seems a little bit naive. What am i missing ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using a very deep theorem for an elementary result. Besides, pointwise here means at every point, not just almost everywhere. Dirichlet's Theorem only gives almost everywhere convergence.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ the function $f$ is continuous and it is of bounded variation. Hence the Fourier series converges to $f$ at every point. It is not true that the Fourier series of any continuous function converges pointwise. Dirichlet's Theorem only gives convergence almost everywhere, not everywhere.